# Coloring a range of cells (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that checks a specific column. If that particular column (col 21) is FALSE, then I would like to color only cells in columns 8, 9 and 10 in the that particular row where there is a false.

```
For i = 9 To LastRow
     If Sheets("Test").Cells(i, 21).Value = "False" Then
     Sheets("Test").Cells(i, 8:10).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
     End If
Next i
```

This does not work. Is there a way to do this in one line, rather than coloring each cell at once?

Thanks

Comment: Any specific reason to avoid Conditional formatting which is way faster and native to Excel?

Comment: I am not sure if Conditional Formatting can do what I want. I would like to highlight the 3 columns (cols 8, 9 and 10) irrespective of what they contain, only by what col21 contains.

Comment: You can definitely achieve it through conditional formatting. If you wish, I can provide the answer.

Comment: Go on - I thought cond. format. depends on what is in cell..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your code update this line: **`ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, 8), ws.Cells(r, 10)).Font.Color = vbRed`**

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ShowFalse()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, r As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 21).End(xlUp).Row

    If lr > 8 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For r = 9 To lr
            If Not IsError(ws.Cells(r, 21)) Then
                If ws.Cells(r, 21).Value = False Then
                    ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, 8), ws.Cells(r, 10)).Font.Color = vbRed
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

---

To make it faster use `AutoFilter`

---

```
Public Sub ShowFalseAF()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, fCol As Range, clrCols As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 21).End(xlUp).Row

    If lr > 8 Then
        Set fCol = ws.Range(ws.Cells(9, 21), ws.Cells(lr, 21))
        Set clrCols = ws.Range(ws.Cells(9, 8), ws.Cells(lr, 10))

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        fCol.AutoFilter 1, False
        If fCol.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
            ws.Rows(9).Hidden = ws.Cells(9, 21) <> False
            clrCols.Font.Color = vbRed
            ws.Rows(9).Hidden = False
        End If
        fCol.AutoFilter
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please explain what autofilter does?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: `AutoFilter` eliminates the `For` loop, and highlights the entire visible range (required columns only) at once - which is much faster when working with large files (it will not be noticeable for a small number of rows)

Answer (score 3):

Following our discussion in the comments, follow the steps below to apply conditional formatting in MS Excel on selected cells, range or column based on another column's value.

Step #01. Select the range(8:10 - H:J) in which you want to apply formatting.

Step #02. Click on 'Conditional Formatting' in the Home tab.

Step #03. Click on 'New Rule' and then select 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format'

Step #04. Provide the formula below

```
=OR($U1=FALSE,$U1="FALSE")
```

Step #05. Click on Format to apply desired formatting and then click OK.

[image]